# Accesing Rstudio and H2O Flow in a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, rstudio, h2o

I'm trying to test both RStudio and H2O in a single instance of amazon EC2. Started with an AMI prepared with RStudio and had no trouble. After that, downloaded and installed H2O succesfully and the package for R.

Problem is, while both Rstudio and H2O are up and running, I cannot connect to the H2O flow web interface (DNS: h2o port). I don't know if there's some kind of conflict between the two web interfaces or there's other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access Flow if you open TCP port 54321 in the instance's security group.

Comment: I tried that with no positive result. After that I tried opening everything for my IP and still nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure about your EC2/SG setup. We run RStudio and H2O on our EC2 cluster all the time - nothing special to be done there other than opening up the ports. Which AMI are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The full set of ports I open are:

- Ports 54321 and 54322, both TCP and UDP
- Port 8787  (for RStudio) (TCP only)
- Port 22 (for SSH)  (TCP only)

Using the H2O AMI I find I need to SSH in to create a special user and password for RStudio. (I create the account as not allowed login, by giving it a /bin/false shell, for a bit of extra security).

If you will only use H2O from the RStudio running on EC2, then I don't think you need to open 54321/54322; just opening 8787 will be sufficient.